# Updating two fields in the same query using the same calculated value

Tags: mysql

I have the following query to update a table where the field is calculating as a rank based on a score field.

```
update `table` T1 set Rank=
(select count(*)+1 from (select * from `table` WHERE platform='asdf') T2 
WHERE T2.score > T1.score AND T2.platform='asdf') WHERE T1.platform='asdf'
```

However, I want to set a difference field from the old rank which uses the previous rank to calculate `(rankDiff=rank - f)` where

```
f = ` (select count(*)+1 from (select * from `table` WHERE platform='asdf') T2 
    WHERE T2.score > T1.score AND T2.platform='asdf') WHERE T1.platform='asdf'`
```

Does anybody know a way I can do this? I was thinking of joining the table with the information but I can't get the JOIN ON part right with the count calculation (possible?).

Anyone have any ideas how this can be done without just straight up duplicating the code (which is an option, but not an elegent one!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are trying to achieve:

```
update `table` T1 set Rank=(select count(*)+1 from (select * from `table`
WHERE  platform='asdf') T2 
WHERE T2.score > T1.score AND T2.platform='asdf') WHERE T1.platform='asdf' as NewRankew), 
RankDiff=Rank-NewRank
```

Comment: I think it is, except I want to also set Rank to ranknew at the same time. Running this I get a SQL error unknown column ranknew

Comment: Not quite, I would like to set Rank to 
(select count(*)+1 from (select * from `table` WHERE  platform='asdf') T2 WHERE T2.score > T1.score AND T2.platform='asdf') 
and set 
RankDiff=Rank-(select count(*)+1 from (select * from `table` WHERE  platform='asdf') T2 WHERE T2.score > T1.score AND T2.platform='asdf')

Comment: @DannyBirch, If I understood right then it is the above... RankDiff is a different field correct?